# Azure Application Insights doesn't show live metrics when using Java 8 and application insights SDK version 1.0.8

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, gradle, azure-application-insights

I am using azure application insights for logging in my application, It is a spring boot application with gradle. I am using application insights as an appender in my logback-spring.xml. I am using Java 8 and Appinsights version 1.0.8. I do not see live metrics. I see the message as App is Offline or update to newer version of SDK. I tried updating build.gradle to use new appinsights version 2.14.0 and the build fails. The build runs fine when using older version 1.0.8. I am new to Gradle. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you try and show us a [Miniaml, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show us exactly what you are doing and exactly how it's failing?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Below is my build.gradle; logback-spring.xml and applicationinsights.xml. The problem is when I am running the build with appinsights version 1.0.8, the build is passing but when I update to any newer version 2.0.+ the build is failing. I am new to this space. Apologize if I am still missing anything. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Looks like I cannot add files in here. But below is the error I get when I update the SDK, 2020-05-29T02:47:29.6715081Z * What went wrong:
2020-05-29T02:47:29.6730479Z Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration3'.
2020-05-29T02:47:29.6731155Z > Could not find com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-web:2.14.0.
2020-05-29T02:47:29.6731557Z   Searched in the following locations:

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue about live metrics in the Java application insights SDK : https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/issues/1212#issuecomment-594784792

According to this post, live metrics are not fully supported by the Java SDK :(

The table in the link https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/azure-monitor/app/live-stream#supported-features-table says that the supported feature requires Java application insights SDK version V2.0.0+